# Integration Test for application which is talking to external API

Tags: spring-boot, unit-testing, junit5, spring-boot-test

I have an spring boot web application which is talking with external APIs, I need to write a integration unit test cases for my controllers
I'm using testWebClient

```
    webTestClient
        .get()
        .uri(uriBuilder -> uriBuilder.path("/my-application-api").build())
        .header(HttpHeaders.ACCEPT, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE)
        .exchange()
        .expectStatus()
        .isOk()
```

my-application-api is present in controller class and it's method it talking to external api
and doing some operations

with out using external tools like wiremock/mockserver can I create a fake server kind of thing and write Mock API's myself ??

Answer (score 2):

The simplest approach, which I use most often, is to hide the external API behind a facade and mock that facade during the integration tests.

If taking away one layer of integration worries you, add a set of characterisation/contract tests to your real façade implementation.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use WireMock/Mockserver (which I thing can improve the level of confidence you get from your tests), you could:

- Simply use `@MockBean private MyRemoteClient myRemoteClient` and then use Mockito to specify the return values manually
- Add a layer of abstraction by introducing an interface for your API client that defines the method. Provide the real implementation in your production code and for your tests, you can provide an implementation with your hard-coded implementation and add it to the context with `@TestConfiguration`/`@Bean`/`@Primary`